# How to use dojo/promise/Promise.cancel() in an Inteceptor Pattern

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am looking to implement an Inteceptor Pattern for an application specific AJAX controller.

Any AJAX request in my application would call Authenticator.request(), which would intercept the response, check for certain statuses (e.g. 401, 403, 503), perform application specific display function based on them (i.e. display a LoginDialog if status 401 is received). My issues stem from confusion around dojo's Promises.

1. How can I pass through successful requests back to the original calling method?
2. When I call dojo.promise.Promise.cancel(), I would expect chaining to stop. However, this simply runs the errback function. This means that logic needs to be placed in every errback method in the calling function to differentiate between a cancelled request vs an error.

Could anyone explain to me how to use Promises in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Here's an example of what I thought I could do...

```
require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
    auth = { 
        request: function() {
            var promise = request(arguments);

            return promise.always(function (response) {
                console.log("always called", response);
                switch (response.response.status)
                {
                    case 404:
                        console.log(404, response);
                        return "cancelled";
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

auth.request('example.json').then(function(text){ console.log('success!', text) }, function(error){
    console.log('error!', error);
});
```

In case this helps anyone in the future, here is what I eventually implemented (based off of Dave's answer)...

```
require(["dojo/request", "dojo/errors/CancelError"], function(dRequest, CancelError){
    auth = { 
        request: function(url, options) {
            var promise = dRequest(url, options);

            return promise.response.then(
                function (response) {
                    return response;
                },
                function (error) {
                    var error,
                        cancelError = new CancelError(error.message);
                    cancelError.response = error.response;
                    console.log("error", error, cancelError);

                    switch (error.response.status)
                    {
                        case 404:
                            console.log(404, "canceled");
                            throw cancelError;
                    }
                    throw error;
                }
            );
        },
        cancelTrap: function (errorBack, cancelBack) {
            return function (error) {
                throw (error instanceof CancelError) 
                    ? cancelBack && cancelBack(error) || error 
                    : errorBack && errorBack(error) || error;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

... it can then be used like so...

```
r = auth.request('something.json');
r.then(
    function(text){
        console.log('success! > this', this)
        console.log('success!', text)
        return text;
    }, 
    auth.cancelTrap(
        function (error) {
            console.log('error!', error);
            throw error;
        },
        function (cancelError) {
            console.log('cancelError!', cancelError);
            throw cancelError;
        }
    )
).then(
    function(text){
        console.log('success2!', text)
    }, 
    auth.cancelTrap(
        function (error) {
            console.log('error2!', error);
            throw error;
        },
        function (cancelError) {
            console.log('cancelError2!', cancelError);
            throw cancelError;
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: If you 'cancel' a request, what do you want to happen?

Comment: I would expect .then() not to react to it. For example if a widget uses .then(successFunc, errorFunc) and the promise was cancelled, I would want the widget to have to handle a cancelled state within the errorFunc. Just doesn't seem right.

Comment: One idea I have had was to apply the interceptor on the errorFunc() function instead of on the request(). Since it appears that a cancelled state must be handled within the errorFunc() and needed logic is really just handling certain error statuses, this seems like an ok solution.

Comment: I think the callbacks will all be called if they are present. So if Dojo (or your own code) has deemed a promise has been rejected then all of your errbacks will be called. I'm not sure how you could handle an error and then stop it propagating, if you've already attached the errback handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

promises are really powerful, I think you should try and understand the two paths of execution that are made available through the `then` function (assuming `always` is just a shortcut for calling `then` with the same function as both params) :

`promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback)`

- returns a promise.
- This promise is resolved (success) if :
- either the successCallback *or* the errorCallback return a value. The promise is either resolved with this value, or if this value is a promise, it is resolved with the resolution of this promise.
- This promise rejected (error) if :
- either the successCallback *or* the errorCallback throw an error.

Further, if no errorCallback is provided, if the original promise is rejected (error), this is bubbled up to the next level that does provide an error handler, so if I do this :

```
promise.then(func1).then(func3).then(finalFunc, errorHandler);
promise.reject(someError);
```

Then `errorHandler` is invoked with `someError`.

What this all means is, if you don't want to deal with an error at a certain level, just don't, let it bubble up the chain and implement *one* error handler at the highest level. If you want to deal with only certain errors, you can "wrap it or trap it" like this :

```
promise.then(successFunction, function(error) {
    if(error.code > 400) {
         // do something clever, maybe just send an empty result up the chain
         return []; // goes to successCallbacks!
    } else {
        throw error; // pass it to the next errorHandler
    }
});
```

So finally, to wrap up and attempt to answer your questions :

How can I pass through successful requests back to the original calling method?

You can simply `return` and the value will be passed to the next successHandler.

When I call dojo.promise.Promise.cancel(), I would expect chaining to stop. However, this simply runs the errback function. This means that logic needs to be placed in every errback method in the calling function to differentiate between a cancelled request vs an error.

Unfortunately you are not allowed to halt chaining, promises are designed to robustly pass to completion. You can however *not* place an errback  at every junction, only add one when you really need it, and your solution should be quite clean.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. This clears up a lot of misconceptions I had with Promises.